# Fade div background when text is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

```
function showText(text) {
    $("#messages").append(text + "</br>");
    $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight); 
    //line above is to automatically scroll the div to last added text
}
```

I want the background of the added lines, to fade in and then fade out (it should fade out after half a second or something like that, just to call the attention of the user).
I don't know how to use css. If it's possible, the color of the fade should be something like lightbulb-yellow, as if it was highlighted :P
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the exact thing you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyStaples/G2tqd/

```
$.fn.bgColorFade = function(userOptions) {
// starting color, ending color, duration in ms
var options = $.extend({
    start: "yellow",
    end: "#fff",
    time: 500
}, userOptions || {});
$(this).css({
    backgroundColor: options.start
}).animate({
    backgroundColor: options.end
}, options.time);
return this;
};

$(".test").bgColorFade({
  time: 500
});
```

Then reverse it to have it fade out.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen! :D If only I had seen this before... xD